# Can't change theme in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

So I have been using Visual Studio Code for about a year now, as a Student, I have always been using the **Material Theme Darker High Contrast** since, I don't know exactly what happened, but the theme got updated and the older version, which I used, has been renamed to **Legacy - Material Theme Darker High Contrast**, I don't like the new version so I wished to go back, but whenever I change my them to the legacy version and save the file (settings.JSON), it reverts back to the non legacy version, this isn't just the case with this either, whatever I do with the **workbench.colorTheme** setting, it will revert back to **Material Theme Darker High Contrast**,. it's very annoying. Here is my JSON

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.matchBrackets": false,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker High Contrast",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

So how do I change my theme?
Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Uninstall and re-install the theme extension from the extension store
2. Manually delete the updated theme from the theme directory of vs code from your system.
3. Disable and re-enable the theme.

Happy to help!